# How to set editor specific context for statusbar items in custom VS Code extension?

Tags: typescript, webview, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a custom editor as a VS Code extension. I want to expose status bar items only when this custom editor is active.

What is the recommended path to exposing editor context specific status bar items?

I've tried to conditionally show/hide status bar items based on the output of `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`. So far I've learned, at least with custom editors, that the output is always `undefined`.

Currently I'm relying on this `undefined` output to toggle visibility but I'm looking for something more concrete.