# How to access the current editor document from a TreeView or Webview panel in a custom VS Code extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I would like to access the active editor document from a TreeView or Webview panel similar to how the "Outline" panel works by reading the document and providing an an easy to navigate nested tree of classes, methods and properties.

I've tried to bring the instantiated `vscode.TextDocument` context into each of these panel views but it only appears to be accessible to the `CustomTextEditorProvider` via the `resolveCustomTextEditor` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation involves interacting with the VS Code API, specifically focusing on how to communicate between different parts of the extension (like TreeView, WebView, and the active text editor)

You can access the active text editor in VS Code using `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`. This gives you the currently focused editor, and the active text editor has a document property, which is a `vscode.TextDocument`. This represents the content of the currently open file.

To update your TreeView or WebView when the active editor changes, you need to listen to the `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` event. Register an event listener that updates your TreeView or WebView whenever the active editor changes.

Now for communicating with TreeView or WebView

Use VS Code's messaging API to send messages between different parts of your extension. When the active editor changes, send a message to your TreeView or WebView with the necessary information extracted from the TextDocument.
In your TreeView or WebView, listen for these messages and update the view accordingly.

Implementing in WebView

WebViews are more isolated but can still communicate with the rest of your extension using message passing.
When you receive a new active document, send its content or relevant data to the WebView using postMessage.
In your WebView's JavaScript, listen for these messages and update the content.

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

function updateActiveDocumentContent() {
    const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (activeEditor) {
        const documentContent = activeEditor.document.getText();
        // Send this content to TreeView or WebView
        // For WebView: webViewPanel.webview.postMessage({ content: documentContent });
        // For TreeView: update your TreeDataProvider
    }
}

// Listen for active editor changes
vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(() => {
    updateActiveDocumentContent();
});

// Initial update
updateActiveDocumentContent();
```

Comment: Neftali, I think this is the most comprehensive explanation I've seen on the Stacks. I very much appreciate the time you spared. A++

Comment: Something I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77882989/how-to-set-editor-specific-context-for-statusbar-items-in-custom-vs-code-extensi) relates to the variable `activeEditor` as being `undefined` when switching to my custom editor. Is this a known issue, expected output or an issue with my implementation?